# Different calculation figure in arithmetic TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting diff. figures in my below equation written.

```
SELECT 9.36 + 9.36 / ( 284.36 ) * 15.64 = 9.8748065528 (CORRECT)
SELECT 18.72 / ( 284.36 ) * 15.64 = 1.0296131056  (INCORRECT)
```

I have total (9.36 * 2) Which I am putting in second select statement and gives incorrect amount.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just read about operator precedence.. You will know why... Here the order is /,*,+

Comment: When working with 1 or more operator I ALWAYS try and specify the order I want everything calculated using parenthesis. Good read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: Ok, I want to calculate Fixed Margin for total records. For example, I have 284.360 with fixed margin 15.64 - it comes with 300 - But 284.36 is collection of two records - 9.36 and 275 - I want each one's separate fixed margin..

Answer (score 1):

The equations are not the same.

The second statement is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT (9.36 + 9.36) / ( 284.36 ) * 15.64
```

not

```
SELECT 9.36 + 9.36 / ( 284.36 ) * 15.64
```

Remember your Order of Operations.

Answer (score 0):

THIS is what I want.

SELECT 9.36 + (9.36 / ( 284.36 ) * 15.64)